# PHP 7.0 not inserting in MySQL row using INSERT Command

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

Here is the insert code which was working on PHP 5.3 and NOT on 5.4 and above.

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (`username`, `password`, `primary_number`, `alternate_number`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssss", $username, $password, $primaryno, $alternateno, $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
```

It was working in some old PHP Version correctly, when I changed the server, PHP 7.1 was selected by default. 
I was quite frustrated as I was unable to find the problem. But now I have found it I don't know why it happened

[image]

The code perfectly works fine in PHP 5.2, 5.3 but not above that. What modifications do I need to make so it works in other version also?

Comment: checkout your error log

Comment: You need to configure PHP so you can see error messages (either on screen or logged into a file). And it won't hurt either to rewrite your code and add some error checking (I'd suggest to just configure mysqli to throw exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the functions you are using were related to functions that **"has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0"** :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-bind-param.php

The PHP version it was removed tends to stick with the PHP version your issue is happening so i firstly insight that, but i've tried your code and it seems to work for me.
Try using `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` and check `phpinfo();` for differences, and maybe try some other MySQL version.

I tried your code and it seems to work fine with :

-PHP 5.5.12
-MySQL 5.6.17
-Apache 2.4.9

Hope this helps.

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` != `mysqli_bind_param()`. Manual pages for [mysqli_prepare()](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare), [mysqli_stmt_bind_param()](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_bind_param) and [mysqli_stmt_execute()](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_execute) do not mention anything about it and they're all available in my local PHP/7.0.2 installation, yet this was chosen as accepted answer. What am I missing?